# ListBox with IValueConverter of Bool To YesNo...almost works, but not quite

Tags: silverlight, binding, mvvm, ivalueconverter

I'm attempting to use a Listbox to display Yes/No and bind to a bit field in my Sql Server Database.
Does my code (especially my binding) look correct?

When using this, it work for creating a record with a Yes (true) statement, or No (false) statement, I can even update a No (false) to a Yes (true) in the database....but I can't edit a Yes (true) to a No (False)...if I debug everything looks good, right up until I hit my RiaService, then using Sql Profiler, the field isn't updated.

Oh yeah, If I bind this same code to a varchar field and exclude the converter, everything works fine.

```
public class ConvertBoolToYesNo : IValueConverter
{
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return null;
            string outValue;
            bool inValue = (bool)value;

            outValue = inValue ? "Yes" : "No";

            return outValue;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return null;
            bool? outValue;
            string inValue = (string)value;
            inValue = inValue.Trim();

            if (inValue == "Yes")
            {
                outValue = true;
            }
            else
                if (inValue == "No")
                {
                    outValue = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
                }
        return outValue;
    }
<ListBox x:Name="lbCounselExempt"
 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Choices}"
 DisplayMemberPath="Name"                                 
 SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Model.CounselExempt, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource ConvertBoolToYesNo}}"
 SelectedValuePath="Name"
 Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonList}" />
```

Comment: I think I solved or at least found a work around for my own question.  In SQL Table I have a field set to 'bit' and it's nullable.  In my entity model I had the field property for Nullable set to 'false'.  Once I set it to '(None)', things started working.  Not sure why, I found quite a few posts on the subject, I just got lucky that one of my other bit fields was working properly and I could compare the settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you can debug it and see that the value is changed right before you make the call to your RIA Service, then it isn't a valueconverter issue. More likely is it something fuzzy with the transport/serialization of the object to the server side.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer...I think I got it...I don't completely understand the underlying problem, but at least I have a work around.